# What can I do to secure my towns/castles/hovels from climbing spiders?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

So with the latest patch spiders can climb walls. What can we do to secure our towns/castles/hovels against these new mobile menaces? Does adding a lip to the wall work? Or is there some block they won't climb?

Comment: Water and lava? :P

Comment: Look on the bright side -- Notch could have made climbing *creepers*.

Comment: im in ur base, climbin ur wallSSSSSSSSSSSS-

Answer (score 34, accepted):

This answer has gone through many, many edits, so I decided to overhaul it. (Minecraft Forums user Thescorpi0on did a [number of tests](http://www.minecraftforum.net/viewtopic.php?f=1020&t=149154#p2137656) on this.)

#### Things that *will* stop spiders:

- A lip extending off of your wall
- Ladders on the top of your wall

#### Things that *won't* stop spiders:

- Torches
- Signs
- Cacti (it will injure them but they can climb up them)
- Glass
- Sandstone
- Ladders going all the way up your wall (they will start climbing at the bottom all the way up)

Comment: How high does the glass have to be?  Does a 1-block-high band work?

Comment: Mine was two blocks, but it fell right as it touched the first block. A one block wide band should suffice.

Comment: Too many edits...although I'm still curious why the first time, the spider climbed up the dirt tower and then slipped on the glass, even though spiders can climb glass.

Comment: Well, I do appreciate the effort you put into the answer at least

Comment: Ladders work for the same reason a lip works; at least, as far as I understand it, as it takes up the same amount of space in terms of blocks.

Comment: Hey, covering the walls with signs works.

Comment: Is the lip idea adaptable to big fields surrounded by fences?

Answer (score 15):

In addition to the above methods, I've found that a cactus wall around my tower ends up murdering all the spiders. They climb to the top of the cacti and sit there. They can't get to the tower wall because of the necessary one space gap involved with a cactus wall and proceed to die to the cacti spikes.

Answer (score 12):

My house is literally made 100% of water. Try climbing that you damn spiders!

Comment: A MerMAN, father! MerMAN! *cough. Cough*

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen. Seriously, though. If this is real I'd love to see it.

Answer (score 11):

Use my patented Spider Dissuasion Device.

Ready to dissuade:

[image: Ready to dissuade]

Dissuading:

[image: Dissuading]

250% more amusing than lipped walls alone.

(May not be more amusing. May cause damage to livestock, buildings, operatives, sticks, handbags, weddings, and Kuala Lumpur.)

Comment: Haha, definitely the funniest answer.

Answer (score 3):

New update - Spiders can now climb anything but cactus, the lip trick still works though.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Gaming.stackexchange! Do you have a link to the source of this or some other information to back it up, such as pictures or screenshots? Calling the userbase at large "n00bz' as well is unlikely to paint you favorably. I can't find anything about an update, *especially* considering minecraft.net is overwhelmed, currently.

Comment: They can climb cactus, they'll just be killed eventually.

Answer (score 2):

I assume they wouldn't be able to climb past a lip, just common sense really.

Unless they had a bucket of water of course...

Comment: I was thinking the same thing but one of my friends swore that he had one climb over a lip to the top of the tower. So I came here for some confirmation one way or another.

Comment: Is the lip idea adaptable to big fields surrounded by fences?

Answer (score 1):

Easy, build a roof and add a door to your house, and also make sure windows are only 1 block, not two. (horizontal and vertical) Now wait for the daytime to kill the spiders (since spiders are not aggressive in the light). That or move back to your hidey hole.