# Can players spawn on glass blocks in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know that mobs can't spawn on glass blocks as can be seen from this [question and answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/16444/can-mobs-spawn-on-glass).

But what about players? If I have my spawn area covered in glass blocks, will I be able to spawn on them?

Comment: This is very similar to your [previous question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/403615/171580), it should just be combined into one. Also, you tagged both games, please specify which one you actually mean.

Comment: @FabianRöling Yes. It is similar to my previous question, but it isn't the same. I don't agree with combining them into one question since it is for different blocks. Not the same.

Comment: @FabianRöling I tagged both games because I want to know the answer for both games. Both Bedrock and Java.

Comment: Yes you can, because every question asks about spawning over transparent and partial blocks, since you just ask about the same mechanics. So you can combine all 3 in a single one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Yes, glass doesn't deter players.

First of all, when a player first enters a world, the game will try to spawn them in a generous area around the *"world spawn point"* (a point not far away from 0x 0y 0z) on a grass block; [there are enough contingencies in the system that the spawn cannot be prevented](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Player_spawning):

> If there are absolutely no grass blocks, the player spawns directly at the world spawn point, which can even result in players spawning above the Void if there are no blocks at that location.

Secondly, glass doesn't prevent all mob spawns; notably, it doesn't prevent monster spawners from spawning its monsters - which makes it vital for making mob farms that **won't** be blown up a surprise Creeper.

Thirdly, it would be really weird if this was the one and only rule that was shared between players entering a world and NPCs being generated. The game spawns the first player on a new world during noon, so it doesn't prevent players from spawning in light level 15, and all *Minecraft* servers would be completely at the mercy of griefers [if two buckets of water or players AFKing near center](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Spawn#Monsters) would completely prevent people from joining a server.