# How can I prevent spiders from climbing over walls?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can I do to secure my towns/castles/hovels from climbing spiders?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14566/what-can-i-do-to-secure-my-towns-castles-hovels-from-climbing-spiders)

What is the best way to create a structure / fort with no roof in Minecraft that can prevent  spiders from climbing in at night?

Comment: There it is! Feel free to close as a duplicate.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to simply make a [protruding rim](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Safe_Home#Spiders) around the outside using any type of block.  The spiders will climb until the reach the rim, but will not be able to go any higher.  I like to use stairs for a nice sloped effect.

If you don't like that method, you can also create a vertical 1-block gap and fill it with either **iron bars** or **glass panes**.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a surrounding wall and along the top part of the wall with blocks going out from your camp in the shape of an upside down L. This will make it so that the spiders cannot climb over your walls. If you dont get what I mean ill post a pic for you.