# How can I make a treehouse that spiders can't get into?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

As a first-night house in Minecraft, I always make a tree house, but spiders keep messing with me. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Did you have a look at these relevant questions: [blocks spiders cannot climb](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66050/are-there-any-blocks-that-spiders-cannot-climb) and [ways to secure buildings from spiders](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14566/what-can-i-do-to-secure-my-towns-castles-hovels-from-climbing-spiders)? What kind of problem are you having? Are they are spawning on top of your tree? Are they are climbing into your house?

Comment: for spawning on top just light the top (or ensure no solid blocks are available to spawn)

Comment: They are spawning on top of the tree,even though its lit.

Comment: If it's lit, and you don't have any dark patches that aren't leaves or another transparent block, then they're not spawning up there. More likely there is either a climbable path up, or they're dropping/jumping down from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

spiders actually cannot  pass through spaces that are 1 square wide. If you create a tree house with an entrance of 1 space squared and you bullet proof the roof by making a design that has only 1 square spaces spiders will not be able to get through either from top nor the bottom.

Here is a video of what i mean:

had hard time finding a video but this one explains it at 1:08

GL!

Comment: alternatively you can light the roof so  no spiders spawn there and cut down trees around so the spiders dont jump into your tree house. you still need to 1 square pattern though

Answer (score 1):

I found out a good way to make a treehouse spider proof. First of all as always, keep it lit, because mobs may spawn in your treehouses if unlit. Second, make sure your tree house is away from a cliff or other trees. The Third thing has a lot of explanation. You're going to put half slabs or normal on each side of the tree house. This prevents spiders from climbing onto the house.

Example of a spider proof wall:

[image: TAKE THAT SPIDERS!]

So thoses are the ways of making your treehouse spider proof! Have a good time building!

Answer (score 0):

My answer is this, Replace any wood on the top of your house with a non burnable block and put lava down all over the top with glass under it. So mobs don't spawn on the roof, and your house is lit.

Comment: ... not to mention "on fire".