# Is there a block that spider can't climb

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any blocks that spiders cannot climb?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66050/are-there-any-blocks-that-spiders-cannot-climb)

I want to build a wall. The spider can climb the wall. I am wondering if is there a block that spider can't climb?

Comment: Try looking here: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66050/are-there-any-blocks-that-spiders-cannot-climb or http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14566/what-can-i-do-to-secure-my-towns-castles-hovels-from-climbing-spiders