# Can spiders climb glass blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was wanting to make a greenhouse out of glass, and I want my house to be spider proof. I have read that glass planes, but could not find suitable information concerning glass blocks.

Can spiders climb glass blocks?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Refer to this question.
[Are there any blocks that spiders cannot climb?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66050/are-there-any-blocks-that-spiders-cannot-climb)

Essentially, they can climb anything, but put signs on the walls, or have an overhang and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank you, Ben. Forgot you could just edit the question.