# ( Java Minecraft 1.14.3 ) Is there any block that spiders can´t climb?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there any block that spiders can't climb ? It's really messing up my farm  and I'm looking for a way to prevent it. :D Thanks.

Comment: Spiders for sure can't climb cactus *without being harmed*, but I think they still can climb it. If you make an overhang the spiders will get stuck on it, but they will still try to climb the wall leading up to the overhang. According to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/66050/are-there-any-blocks-that-spiders-cannot-climb?rq=1) very old post, spiders can't climb walls with signs, but that has probably changed by 1.14.

Comment: @Nik3141 yeah I tried signs but they climbed it and I found that someone said they can´t climb cocoa beans so I will try it out

Comment: @Koterko also try fence. They used to not be able to climb it, but i'm not sure anymore. :)

Comment: If you fill the walls with end rods, at least cave spiders only climb on top of the lowest one.

Answer (score 4):

[image: The way Spiders can't climb]They can climb on any block (except lava, since they die before getting on the walls), but that isn't good idea to prevent them from coming in, as the lava can burn everything. If you use fences, place a carpet on top of them (or a slab, dosen't matter), and if you use blocks, put a trapdoor on them and close it. These blocks stop them from climbing up them, because the blocks the spider climbs on must be flat (e.g. a 3-block stone wall), so carpet on fences and trapdoors on blocks are the best solutions to stop them. The walls don't need to be that big, but since Spiders could try to jump and eventually get on the carpet/trapdoor, ignoring it completely, it's better to make it 3 blocks high.

Hope this helps.