# How do I get monsters to spawn in a certain place?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

Okay, I have an SMP server and I don't want monsters to spawn near my spawn area or anywhere within it. Also, I have built castle walls around it and a huge house (which keeps getting destroyed), but they still spawn inside; is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/12358/how-far-do-i-have-to-place-torches-so-that-mobs-will-not-spawn-near-me

Comment: Can someone add a comma in the first sentence and change the title to "How to stop monsters(mobs?) from spawning in a certain place in Minecraft?" I would, but it's too small an edit to suggest since it doesn't count the title.

Answer (score 9):

I suspect this has been asked before, but I can't find the question so I'll answer this one:

Aggressive monsters, with the exception of ghasts, will spawn when the light level is at [7 or below](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Mobs).  Torches are considered a light source of level 14, Lava, Glowstone, and Fire are at level 15.  For each square away from the light source, you drop the light level by 1.  If multiple light sources are affecting that square, the highest light level is taken.  Glass does not lower light levels as it passes through (anymore than the normal amount), water and ice adds an additional 2 levels of penalty.

Monsters also cannot spawn within 24 squares of the player, and monsters will not spawn if you go to sleep in a bed to skip the night.  If every player in SMP is in bed by the time night comes around, then the night will be skipped.

Finally, keep in mind that spiders can now climb walls so even though you have built a wall around your house, you may still find spiders from within. So make sure that you build a roof.

Comment: Also note that spiders cannot cross sandstone, laying it in front of your wall should keep them out.

Comment: @Keaanu It doesn't mention that [on the wiki](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Sandstone). I think that you're thinking of [Soul Sand](http://www.minecraftwiki.net/wiki/Soul_Sand), which spiders can't climb.(I still don't know about just crossing it though.)

Comment: You may be correct

Comment: concerning beds, they are [not always safe](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17377/minecraft-nightmares-or-how-to-not-get-woken-by-mobs), you have to make sure no adjacent square allows mobs to spawn - and if your bed is next to a wall that actually includes the squares on the other side of the wall!

Comment: I was thinking of [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/20155/how-do-minecraft-mobs-behave-in-water/20163#20163).

Comment: If you put a lip on a wall, that should keep spiders out as well.