# How do Minecraft mobs behave in water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Several questions here related to mobs and water:

1. When mobs enter water, do they swim at the top, or will they dive down?
2. Can mobs spawn in the water?
3. I assume mobs can exit water one block deep, but can they climb out from a deeper sheer edge? (Players can, right?)
4. Is there an easy way to make a shoreline mob-proof (without actually using a wall or fence?)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: "Fun" fact: Skeletons / Zombies in the water don't burn up in sunlight.

Comment: that's not fun at all, actually.

Comment: I'd like to suggest an addendum to this question: Will mobs spawn 'in water' if it is one block shallow, or does water prevent all mob spawning besides squid, period?

Comment: @Zibbobz "one block shallow water" counts as just water, and will prevent non-water-based mobs from spawning. This can also be done with a single layer of transparent blocks, half-blocks (like slabs or stairs), or lava.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1. Most mobs swim to the surface, even if you're submerged beneath them.
   The exceptions are:

- [Squids](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Squid)
- [Dolphins](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dolphin)
- [Turtles](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Turtle)
- [Fish](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Fish_(mob))
- [Guardians](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Guardian)/[Elder Guardians](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Elder_Guardian), which swim after and attack the player underwater
- [Zombies](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Zombie), which sink and become [Drowned](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Phantom)
- [Husks](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Husk) turn into Zombies which turn into Drowned
- [Drowned](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Drowned) mobs, which swim and attack the player underwater
- [Other undead mobs](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Undead), which sink and move along the bottom, but cannot swim
- [Phantoms](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Phantom), which will sometimes dive into water and then quickly die
- Also note that Skeleton arrows can and will pierce water

2. Most mobs will not spawn in or on water. Again, this comes with the exceptions:

- Squids can spawn in any body of water, as far as 18 blocks below sea level
- Dolphins spawn in non-frozen ocean biomes
- Fish spawn [in various places underwater](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Soul_Sand)
- Guardians/Elder Guardians spawn in and near [Ocean Monuments](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Ocean_monument)
- Drowned mobs spawn at the bottom of oceans, rivers or swamps

3. Since most mobs swim to the surface of standing water, they can get to the top of a sheer edge and exit from there. No mobs can swim up waterfalls though, so you can keep them all down using running water. Non-Drowned undead mobs will stay at the bottom of water and will be unable to escape.
4. A long [Soul Sand gate](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Soul_Sand) can be built along the shoreline, which will prevent mobs from crossing it. These gates can be traversed by players using minecarts on tracks placed over the Soul Sand. From [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Soul_Sand):

> When placed on the ground in front of
> a two-block high doorway, soul sand
> prevents players from going through it
> from that direction, making it useful
> for building one-way passages or
> invisible barriers. This affects mobs
> too as they have to jump to get out of
> the slowing effects of the block, thus
> are unable to get through the door.
>
> Because minecart tracks can be laid on
> Soul Sand like most other block
> materials, this quirk can be exploited
> to create minecart-only gates (by
> placing soul sand on both sides of the
> doorway). This is one of the few ways
> to allow minecart tracks to go
> directly inside a secure area without
> risking wandering mobs getting in.

Here's a snapshot of a small one I built beside my house, with a crossing point for players.

[image: A Soul Sand gate along a small shoreline]

Comment: I assume the gate you detail wouldn't work against spiders, pigs, or chickens?

Comment: @NickT make it 1 block wide, and spiders will keep out.

Comment: As of 1.13, zombies no longer swim, and drowned can swim and will attack underwater players.

Comment: @ppperry Cool. Updated to post-1.13 Bedrock Edition mechanics.

Comment: You've forgotten that Husks turn into zombies when underwater, also your drowned link goes to phantoms instead of drowned

Comment: @ppperry Updated. I had initially chosen to omit Husks but they do behave differently in water, yes.

Comment: The soul-sand one-way door thing was removed in minecraft 1.8

Answer (score 13):

To answer the first question:

When mobs enter water they swim to the surface. My son has built a mob "generator" which relies on this principle to draw the mobs to the surface where they die and deposit their goodies for him to collect.

Comment: Answering through my experience how dare you!

Comment: @Ronan - Fastest Gun In The West! Wins every time. Feel free to add your own answer that addresses the other points.

Comment: @ChrisF in this case it's "Most time on their hands"

Comment: First father son combo I have seen on here. +1 for being awesome!

Comment: @Ronan - nope - it's "waiting for a build"

Comment: @ChrisF - You could instead be [sword-fighting](http://xkcd.com/303/) ya know.

Comment: He's probably still saving up to build that diamond-sword so it'll last for the entire compile time under VC++.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, Mobs will die if in water too long. Squids will not die, but they are not mobs and will not harm you. (Note: Squids can't swim upwards. I hope this is useful in case you ever find a squid farm!)

Comment: Squid are mobs – just *passive* mobs.